# How to display the "markdown" in windows 8 apps?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markdown

I have markdown, how i can display formatted text in win 8 apps?

---

**Things i have tried, that may or may not be useful to any answer**

- I tried converting markdown to rtf and show result in RichTextBlock, but I have problem with markdown to rtf converting.

Comment: "I have problem with markdown to rtf converting" Should we guess what the problem is, or maybe you could tell us?

Comment: @spender Rather than continuing down the *RTF* route, is there a better way? What is the best way to display *markdown* in Windows 8 apps? Does Metro have a `Markdown` control?

Comment: I don't know how to convert markdown to rtf it's my problem !I convert markdown to  html and then convert to rtf, but result was ugly!

Comment: I don't know how relevant to your current situation, but I solved the "Display Markdown in WPF" problem by writing a Markdown renderer that generates a FlowDocument. Hope this is of use to you - https://github.com/theunrepentantgeek/Markdown.XAML

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Trickier than I suspected...

I'd suggest using [markdownsharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) to derive html from your markdown and to display that in an html view. <strike>(of which I'm sure "Windows 8 apps" have at least one)</strike>

EDIT

You can then either show this in a WebView or follow [this article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Html-to-RTF-a757fac5) to convert to rtf.

Comment: and what about performance? RichTextBlock is faster that WebView

Comment: for example
Html = @"<body><h2>This is an HTML fragment</h2></body>";
nothing shows

Comment: @user1734917 - What evidence do you have that its faster?  You also are limited if what your Modern UI support.

Comment: for example: webView need source or string, it's additional time to find it

Comment: @user1734917 - How much time do you think is not reasonable.

Comment: I don't know. what about RichTextBlock? How I can display markdown in RichTextBlock? Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this Markdown parser in C#, which exports to HTML and XAML. If you generate XAML, you can access it by using the XamlReader class and display it in a WPF application. (You can also display the HTML version if you choose to.)

https://github.com/PeterWaher/IoTGateway/tree/master/Content/Waher.Content.Markdown

It's part of a larger project:
https://github.com/PeterWaher/IoTGateway/